# Solved! How to use cache.put to add a jpg to the cache?

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, cacheapi

This question concerns the javascript cache api.

I have no problem using **cache.add** to add jpgs to the cache.  But so far I have not figured out how to use **fetch and cache.put** to do the same thing.  I have done a lot of searching and skimmed through a lot of posts but so far I have not seen a basic example.

The following code adds jpg_url to the cache as a key.  But when my pwa tries to display jpg_url offline, no image is displayed.  Apparently my code is not actually saving the jpg in the cache.  What am I missing?

**Update: Solved!** cache_url points to a jpg. The code below will save that jpg in the cache with cache_url as the key. The secret sauce is doing **await response.blob()**

```
async function cache_fetch (cache,cache_url) {
    options = {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}
    }
    response = await fetch(cache_url, options)
    .then (async function(response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            my_blob = await response.blob();
            cache.put(cache_url,new Response(my_blob, {type:'image/jpeg'}))
            .then(function() {
            // do stuff
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
            // do other stuff
            });
        }   else {
            // handle status not 200
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // handle fetch error
    });
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to view the JPG offline? If you want to be able to go to `jpg_url` in your browser, you need to fetch the JPG manually from the cache and return in in your service worker's fetch listener. AFAIK, the browser doesn't do it automatically

Comment: The project is a Leaflet map.  The following Leaflet command will add an image to the map as an overlay.  
L.imageOverlay(jpg_url, bounds).addTo(my_map);


If I add jpgs to the cache using cache.add and then open the map offline, the image for jpg_url is retrieved from the cache and displayed on the map.

However, I have a use case where I want to use fetch and cache.put instead of cache.add